# React route to be render INSIDE another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this components structure:

[image]

I need based on 2 different routes to load inside < OtherComponent> the corresponding route from Router.

I using: `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"`
, and saw some posts talking about using IndexRoute and props.children, but IndexRoute cann't be resolved from react-router-dom, seems it was removed in version 5.

My Router (BrowserRouter) looks like this:

```
<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || '/MyApp'}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                    {/*<IndexRoute component={ProjectsList} /> // The component to send to HomePage's `props.children` when route is '/'*/}
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/editProject" component={ProjectEditor} />
                    {/*<Redirect path="*" to="/" />*/}
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

At the beginning < ProjectsList> is loaded inside < HomePage> (hardcoded),

but from ProjectsList there is a need to edit a project, so need to load the < ProjectEditor> this time inside < HomePage>

## Update

A more detailed structure:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexRoute` was indeed removed from React-Router as of v4. It was used as some sort of "default route"

Routes are now regular components, and can be rendered as part of any component, as long as some top component has a Router definition. Nesting routes allows you to compose the routes and render components with that structure.

Routes also have a render function in which you can render any component

If you need to render `ProjectsList` as children of HomePage, why don't you pass it as a children?

```
<Route path="/" exact render={() => <HomePage><ProjectsList /></HomePage>} />
```

Furthermore, if you're using the latest version of React Router (5.1.0), you can use the `children` props for routes to render, rather than a render prop

```
<Route path="/" exact>
  <HomePage><ProjectsList /></HomePage>
</Route>
```

**Update**

Given your update

> At the beginning < ProjectsList> is loaded inside < HomePage>
>   (hardcoded),
>
> but from ProjectsList there is a need to edit a project, so need to
>   load the < ProjectEditor> this time inside < HomePage>

you can define on your `HomePage` component, inside your render, two routes

```
return (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/editProject"><ProjectsList /></Route>
    <Route path="/"><ProjectsList /></Route>
   </Switch>
)
```

(Depending on the version, you might have to use `render={() => ...}` instead

If for whatever reason, you prefer to have all routes within the same file, you could also do this inside your route definition.

```
<Route path="/" exact>
  <HomePage>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/editProject"><ProjectsList /></Route>
      <Route path="/"><ProjectsList /></Route>
    </Switch>
  </HomePage>
</Route>
```

But in this case, you will have to render `children` in your `HomePage` component

Comment: I used the first approach of having routes inside HomePage, the ProjectsList "/" route worked fine, but the ProjectEditor loaded the component in the whole page instead. I didn't mention that inside <ProjectsList> there are <Project> components and the routing to ProjectEditor should be done from there. (Will update my post accordingly)

Comment: try nesting it in those components, then. You can render a route in any place you want (I can't right now, but I will update later my answer with that info)

Comment: I resolved it by adding this Route to App.js: <Route path="/editProject" component={HomePage} /> (in addetion to: <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />)

Comment: @Zbeedatm can you please share the sample code here?? I have some similar requirement.